# How to remove a div after it has faded out (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a transition in JS. What i want is that once the div has opacity 0, js remove it automatically. The problem is that, i have to exit the div area, and then it removes it. That is because i have a mouseleave, but my question is. How can i delete that div without my mouse leaving the div area? Here's the `CodePen` link:

https://codepen.io/SpeedItaly/pen/PoGPGJZ

```js
function style() {
  h4 = document.getElementById("hover_me");
  header = document.getElementById("header");
  logo = document.getElementById("hover_me1");
  logo.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    logo.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    logo.style.opacity = "0"
  });

  logo.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    header.removeChild(logo);
  });

  menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  if (logo.style.opacity == 0) {
    menu.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    menu.style.opacity = "1"
  }

}

style();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Inter";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222831;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #222831;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}

.logo>h4 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <header class="header" id="header">

    <!-- Start Logo Container -->
    <div class="logo" id="hover_me1">
      <h4 class="text_white" id="hover_me">SpeedItaly</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- End Logo Container -->

    <!-- Start Menu -->
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li><a class="text_white" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Menu-->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `transitionend` event instead.

```js
function style() {
  h4 = document.getElementById("hover_me");
  header = document.getElementById("header");
  logo = document.getElementById("hover_me1");
  logo.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    logo.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    logo.style.opacity = "0"
  });

  logo.addEventListener("transitionend", (e) => {
    header.removeChild(logo);
  });

  menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  if (logo.style.opacity == 0) {
    menu.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    menu.style.opacity = "1"
  }

}

style();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Inter";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222831;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #222831;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}

.logo>h4 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <header class="header" id="header">

    <!-- Start Logo Container -->
    <div class="logo" id="hover_me1">
      <h4 class="text_white" id="hover_me">SpeedItaly</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- End Logo Container -->

    <!-- Start Menu -->
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li><a class="text_white" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Menu-->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `setTimeout`. Specifically, `setTimeout(function() {header.removeChild(logo)},1200)`.

```js
function style() {
  h4 = document.getElementById("hover_me");
  header = document.getElementById("header");
  logo = document.getElementById("hover_me1");
  logo.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    logo.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    logo.style.opacity = "0"
    setTimeout(function() {header.removeChild(logo)},1200)
  });

  menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  if (logo.style.opacity == 0) {
    menu.style.transition = "1200ms ease-in-out opacity"
    menu.style.opacity = "1"
  }

}

style();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Inter";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222831;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #222831;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
}

.logo>h4 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <header class="header" id="header">

    <!-- Start Logo Container -->
    <div class="logo" id="hover_me1">
      <h4 class="text_white" id="hover_me">SpeedItaly</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- End Logo Container -->

    <!-- Start Menu -->
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li><a class="text_white" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Menu-->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `transitionend` CSS event, and remove the node in it.

Also, it is very recommended to [declare your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/8376184) and move CSS declarations into the CSS code, where possible.

```js
function style() {
  const h4 = document.getElementById("hover_me");
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  const logo = document.getElementById("hover_me1");
  const menu = document.getElementById("menu")
  logo.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
    logo.classList.add("hidden")
    logo.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
      logo.remove()
      menu.classList.remove("hidden")
    })
  });


}

style();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Inter";
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222831;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #222831;
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: default;
  transition: 1200ms ease-in-out opacity;
}

.logo>h4 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transition: 1200ms ease-in-out opacity;
}

.menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.menu>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}

.hidden{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <header class="header" id="header">

    <!-- Start Logo Container -->
    <div class="logo" id="hover_me1">
      <h4 class="text_white" id="hover_me">SpeedItaly</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- End Logo Container -->

    <!-- Start Menu -->
    <ul class="menu hidden" id="menu">
      <li><a class="text_white" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="text_white" href="#">Content</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Menu-->

  </header>
  <!-- End Header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to receive your current browser's Transition Events:

```
    const getTransitionEvents = () => {
    let t,
        el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

    let transitions = {
        transition: {
            Start: "transitionstart",
            Run: "transitionrun",
            Cancel: "transitioncancel",
            End: "transitionend"
        },
        OTransition: {
            Start: "oTransitionStart",
            Run: "oTransitionRun",
            Cancel: "oTransitionCancel",
            End: "oTransitionEnd"
        },
        MozTransition: {
            Start: "transitionstart",
            Run: "transitionrun",
            Cancel: "transitioncancel",
            End: "transitionend"
        },
        WebkitTransition: {
            Start: "webkitTransitionStart",
            Run: "webkitTransitionRun",
            Cancel: "webkitTransitionCancel",
            End: "webkitTransitionEnd"
        }
    };

    for (t in transitions) {
        if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
};
```

After that you can just bind the return of this function to a variable

```
const transEvt = getTransitionEvents();
```

and bind eventListeners to it

```
document.addEventListener(transEvt.End, (evt) => {
    // do some cool stuff when the Transition ends
});
```

I use this myself, in a `#just-for-fun` `#work-in-progress` pen called [Simple Image Loop without duplicating slides](https://codepen.io/rene-a-dippe/pen/Rwrvpao) where I rearrange the slides after the transform transition has ended.